# Proving that $(\text{sub}(G),\subseteq)$ is a lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose $G$ is a group and $\text{sub}(G)$ denotes the set of all
>   subgroups of $G$. Then $(\text{sub}(G),\subseteq)$ is a lattice -
>   Prove.

As far as I know, to prove that a structure is a lattice, I just need to ensure that each pair of elements has a "join" (an unique lowest upper bound) and "meet" (an unique greatest lower bound). I can prove it taking examples (and drawing Hasse diagrams) but can't really figure out how to write it down formally in the general case. Any hints/help appreciated.

Comment: join: subgroup generated by the union. Meet: intersection.

Comment: @Crostul I know that

Comment: Where are you having trouble with the proof? Given two subgroups $H,K \subseteq G$, since you already know what the join and meet must be, you just need to show that $H \cap K$ is the greatest lower bound and $\langle H \cup K \rangle$ is the least upper bound of $\{H,K\}$.